# ClipIt functionality: Can't paste in order

Tags: clipboard

Linux is unlike windows due to the lack of choices in software.  For example, in my current Lubuntu 14.04 LTS there is no choices in clipboard managers.  Either you have ClipIt or you have nothing.
      In windows there are a few clipboards you can choose from.  Once you have them installed, there is a way to

> Step 1: Copy 1st store's name;
>   Step 2: Copy 1st stores phone number;
>   Step 3: Copy 1st stores address
>   Step 4: Copy 2nd store's name;
>   Step 5: Copy 2nd store's phone number;
>   Step 6: Copy 2rd stores address
>   ...(etc.)

Then you can
1) paste all (it retains the original order).
2) touch and paste (it retains the original order)

Unfortunately every time I paste something from the clipboard with clipIt, the original order I copied it is totally mixed up.  Thus there is no way to paste the correct phone number and address to the correct store name.  Is there a way to maintain order of entries in ClipIt?  Whenever I select an item, that one item that I just selected appears on top and the order is totally broken.

It also appears that there is no way to *paste all*.

Is there some other clipboard manager in linux that people who use Lubuntu 14.04 LTS can use?  I tried to install glippy, but neither of the following commands had any effect:

```
sudo apt-get install glippy  
sudo add PPA ppa:bikooo/glippy  
a@a-NC210-NC110:~$ sudo apt-get install xclip  
[sudo] password for a:  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package xclip
```

Why does canonical coerce us LXDE users with such brute force to use ClipIt?  Can't LXDE users have a non-lightweight clipboard manager?

Giving users a clipboard manager with the above basic choices is very simple.  What's wrong with canonical for not providing users with something so simple?

Comment: Thanks DK Bose, I have just now read your (Linux is Not Windows) link above.  Great article.

Comment: DK Bose, I say "lack of choices of software" concerning a cut & paste manager since when you open synaptic manager, enter in "clipboard manager" and search via "name and description", only 1 choice comes up: "ClipIt".  Giving users only one choice truly does constitute "lack of choices in software" and "Why does canonical coerce us LXDE users with such brute force to use ClipIt?".

Answer (score 2):

I think CopyQ will satisfy your needs. It is customizable, and easy to use. There is no <kbd>paste all</kbd> button here, but you can select all with a keyboard or mouse and paste. There will be no change in order. Download and learn more from here:

[Ubuntu Handbook: Install CopyQ 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/install-copyq-2-2-ubuntu-1404/)

If there are some packages by default it doesn't mean that you have to use them or can't install others. You can choose other software for your use from Software Center or even outside repositories. You may download a package from Internet suitable for Debian based systems and install it on your machine.

Comment: As for glippy I couldn't enter its site nor I could find a mention about support for Ubuntu 14.04. It seems it has ended it development.

Comment: CopyQ is quite outstanding, too bad canonical doesn't allow users to install via synaptic.